# Configuration file for browsers in Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

My apologies in advance if this question is not so clear but bear with me and I'll try to explain.

I am in the process of re-jigging my personal automation framework based on recent exposure to other frameworks using a different programming language. Usually I create my automation framework using Selenium webdriver java binding but lately I've been using c#.

In the past, i create a baseDriver class that contains the following type of code -

```
public static String browser = System.getProperty("browser");

    static {
    if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
        setWebDriverToFirefox();
    } else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
        if(platform.equalsIgnoreCase("Mac")) {
            CHROME_DRIVER = CHROME_DRIVER + "_mac";
        } else if(platform.equalsIgnoreCase("LINUX")) {
            CHROME_DRIVER = CHROME_DRIVER + "_linux";
        } else {
            CHROME_DRIVER = CHROME_DRIVER + "_win.exe";
        }
        setWebDriverToChrome();
    } else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("safari")) {
        setWebDriverToSafari();
    } else {
        if(os_arch.contains("64")){
            IE_DRIVER = IE_DRIVER + "_x64.exe";
        } else {
            IE_DRIVER = IE_DRIVER + "_win32.exe";
        }

    }
```

This enables me to switch browsers and i run this using testng.xml file

What I want to do now is to have a config file that would enable me define these properties and then access them either using maven or testng when running the tests.

Has anyone implemented something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Create a properties file which references those browsers. Read the properties file in during initialization then access the property when needed to switch.